# My class has a toString() method, how do I use this for hashing in std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++-2013

`MyClass` defines `operator==` and has a non-trivial internal state, but it does provide a `wstring toString()` method, which returns a serialized version of that state. So I thought it would be easy just to use `toString()` with `hash<wstring>` on `std::unordered_set`.

But is it possible to do this in a nice neat way without defining extraneous functor classes? I'm only just getting to grips with C++11 after moving to VS2013 and I thought this was one of the big steps forward, being able to define such things as lambdas?

Thanks for any suggestions how best to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
auto hasher = [](const MyClass &m){ return std::hash<std::wstring>()(m.toString()); };
std::unordered_set<MyClass, decltype(hasher)> set(10, hasher);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't currently work with MSVC [due to a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727957/vc11-beta-compiler-fails-to-compile-lambda-key-comparer-for-maps-and-sets).

Possible workarounds include writing a specialization of `std::hash` for `MyClass`, or storing the lambda in a `std::function<std::size_t(const MyClass &)>` and use that as the hasher's type:

```
std::function<std::size_t(const MyClass &)> hasher = 
                [](const MyClass &m) { return std::hash<std::wstring>()(m.toString()); };
std::unordered_set<MyClass, std::function<std::size_t(const MyClass &)>> set(10, hasher);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to tell `std::hash` how to hash `MyClass` via specialization:

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<MyClass> {
  std::size_t operator () (const MyClass& mc) const {
    return std::hash<std::wstring>()(mc.toString());
  }
};
} // namespace std
```

so you don't need to bother with non-default template parameters for `unordered_set` or `unordered_map`.

Comment: Oddly enough, specializations of `std::hash` seems to be required to provided `result_type` and `argument_type` typedefs for whatever reason. Also, the question asks for lambdas.

Comment: @T.C. The question asks for "suggestions how best to do this." The best way is unquestionably to tell the standard library how to hash the custom type, so that no special handling is required to declare or initialize unordered_maps and unordered_sets.

Comment: @T.C.  The absence of `result_type` and `argument_type` from the Hash requirements in 17.6.3.4 implies that requirement is on specializations provided by the standard library, presumably for users that want to handle them as unary_functions. I find it hard to believe there is a pathological implementation of e.g. unordered_set out there that works properly with any Hash but specifically asserts that its hasher must have those types if and only if it is a `std::hash` specialization.

Comment: The last bullet of [unord.hash] specifically exempts user-defined specializations - "satisfy the requirement that the expression `h(k)`, where `h` is an object of type `hash<Key>` and `k` is an object of type `Key`, shall not throw an exception unless `hash<Key>` is a user-defined specialization that depends on at least one user-defined type", so it sounds to me that the other requirements apply to all specializations, whether provided by the library or the user (though if it does impose such a requirement it sounds to be like a defect, honestly).

Comment: Can you explain why the `template<>` is needed? I did something very similar to this answer and it works, but I didn't use templating at all e.g `struct hash{ std::size_t operator () (const MyClass& mc)... };`